# Fatal Error when calling DB query function

Tags: php, mysql

I currently learning PHP, doing standard CRUD stuff. I'm trying to write  a function (query_entire_table) that I can always use when I want to query all rows of a table, trying to keep it dry.

db.php:

```
<?php
  $db['db_host'] = 'localhost';
  $db['db_user'] = 'root';
  $db['db_pass'] = '';
  $db['db_name'] = 'cms';

  foreach($db as $key => $value){
    define(strtoupper($key), $value);
  }

  $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

  function query_entire_table($tablename){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM " . $tablename;
    $select_all_entries = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    return mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_entries);
  }
?>
```

When I call the function I get the following error:
Fatal error: *Cannot redeclare query_entire_table() (previously declared in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cms/includes/db.php:13) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cms/includes/db.php on line 17*

This is how I call the function:

```
<?php
    $posts_table = query_entire_table('posts');
    while($posts_table){
      //doing some stuff...
    }
?>
```

At this point I only include and call the function once and can't wrap my head around whats happening here.

Comment: Your code doesn’t match the error message. Your db.php file as shown doesn’t even have a line 17 with actual code on it.

Answer (score 4):

Please read the error message carefully:

> Cannot redeclare query_entire_table()

Unlike other languages like JavaScript, PHP does not allow to re-redeclare functions or classes:

```
C:\>php
<?php
function foo(){
}
function foo(){
}
^Z
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare foo() (previously declared in -:3) in - on line 5
```

Wherever you inject `db.php` into your code, you're possibly using the wrong construct. Try something like this:

```
require_once('/path/to/db.php');
```

Please note the **_once** suffix.

Comment: I've seen no code so far but I believe you. What definitions do you find when you use your editor to search for `query_entire_table` in your entire codebase?

Comment: I switched things up a bit and included the db.php file in the navbar partial which is included in the index.php, so the function is available there now. That seems to work. I should have made a posts partial in the first place. Lesson learnt :)

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that you have declared the query_entire_table function somewhere else in your code.

This could also mean you are including db.php more than once. Try using [include_once](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) instead of just a regular include.